# search a particular line and store it in another file using tcl

Tags: parsing, tcl

I have to look into a file log_file.txt which looks something like this:

```
*Jun 20 16:03:52.482 IST: DSL 0-FW: Data0:
*Jun 20 16:03:52.482 IST: DSL 0-FW: 0x20 0x7 
*Jun 20 16:03:52.482 IST: DSL 0-FW: Read from ID 0x369
*Jun 20 16:15:32.591 IST: DSL 0: IPC: Msg_type (4)
*Jun 20 16:15:33.591 IST: DSL 0: IPC: Msg_type (4)
*Jun 20 16:15:33.591 IST: DSL 0: IPC: Msg_type (4)
*Jun 20 16:15:33.839 IST: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface changed state to down
*Jun 20 16:06:21.848 IST: DSL 0-FW: PHY: ack_control: id:0x1
*Jun 20 16:06:21.848 IST: DSL 0-FW: PHY: ackcontrol: 
*Jun 20 16:06:22.192 IST: DSL 0-FW: PHY: ack_control:
```

Here I have to search for lines containing `DSL 0-FW:` and store the line in another file. But I have to exclude the ones with `DSL 0-FW: PHY`.
Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the file line by line and use [`string first`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M7) to filter on the lines you need in the other file. `string first` returns the position of a particular smaller string into a larger string. It returns `-1` if the smaller string is not found.

```
# Assuming that the script is in the same directory as the file... otherwise 
# replace by the file path

# Read the log file
set fin [open "log_file.txt" r]
# Open a file for writing
set fout [open "output.txt" w]

# Read line by line
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    # Check if "DSL 0-FW:" is in the line, if found, proceed
    if {[string first "DSL 0-FW:" $line] != -1} {

        # Check if "DSL 0-FW:" is in the line, if not found, proceed
        if {[string first "DSL 0-FW: PHY" $line] == -1} {
            puts $fout $line
        }
    }
}

close $fin
close $fout
```

Or you could perhaps use a regexp:

```
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    # Check if "DSL 0-FW:" without " PHY" is in the line, if found, proceed
    if {[regexp -- {DSL 0-FW:(?! PHY)} $line]} {
        puts $fout $line
    }
}
```

Where `DSL 0-FW:(?! PHY)` will match if there is a `DSL 0-FW:` not followed by a  `PHY`.

---

Actually, you could even use `string match`:

```
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    # Check if "DSL 0-FW:" is in the line, if found, proceed
    if {[string match "DSL 0-FW:" $line]} {

        # Check if "DSL 0-FW:" is in the line, if not found, proceed
        if {![string match "DSL 0-FW: PHY" $line]} {
            puts $fout $line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first one worked :D
didnt try the others. thanks.
i was wondering if there's something which can, after copying a line into other file, delete that line from the first one.

Comment: @aro No problem, I added the others as alternatives, so it's ultimately your pick =P

Comment: and doesnt, before second `while` the comment should be `check if DSL 0-FW: PHY:` is in the line?

Comment: @aro Nope, the comment is what I meant to be. A single check is needed in the second while. It might be less easily understood, but its shorter. So, it all depends on whether you want your code to be more maintainable, or shorter, but you know you will understand what's there later on, because `regexp` by nature is something that not all people understand easily but if you do, there's nothing wrong using it where it's appropriate.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it.. Thanks.. Is there a way to delete the line from the first file after copying it to the second one?

Comment: @aro You could perhaps erase everything from the first file and write everything from the copied file? Or maybe more efficient would be to delete the first file and rename the second file within the script. I have no experience in reading and writing to the same file at the same time (it's always a mess as it's harder to know where to insert and where to delete in such instances). If that's okay to do the delete/rename, just let me know.

Comment: Can I use something like `[string first "DSL 0-FW" && !"none" $line] == -1` if i want the line with string `DSL 0-FW` but shouldn't contain `none` in the same line? Does this make sense?

Comment: @aro No, you will have to do two separate function calls: `[string first "DSL 0-FW"] != -1 && [string first "none" $line] == -1`. Or with the regex if you're interested: `[regexp -- {^(?!.*none).*DSL 0-FW} $line]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a problem to read the whole log file into memory:

```
set all [split [read -nonewline "log.file"] \n]
set wanted [lsearch -all -inline -regex {DSL 0-FW: (?!PHY:)} $lines]
set fh [open "partial.file" w]
puts $fh [join $wanted \n]
close $fh
```

This uses a negative lookahead to filter out the lines you don't want: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M25